# Does MKL optimize cblas for *major order?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, blas, intel-mkl

I am using `mkl` `cblas_dgemm` and currently have it with `CblasRowMajor`, `CblasNoTrans`, `CblasNotrans`, for my matrices.

I know that `c` is a row major language, whereas `dgemm` is a column major algorithm. I am interested to know if switching the ordering of the matrices will have any affect on the `cblas_dgemm` algorithm if I am linking against `mkl`. Is `mkl` smart enough to do things behind the scenes that I would try to do to optimized the matrix multiplcations? If not, what is the best way to perform matrix multiplications with `mkl`?

Comment: I think I once read that it does, but I cannot find it right now. Why not just multiply two big matrices and see whether there is a difference or not?

Comment: You seem to assuming that there is *one* DGEMM implementation which is used for both the normal and transposed ordered cases. In a performance optimised BLAS like MKL, that is almost certainly not the case and talking about DGEMM as an "algorithm" is likely incorrect. It is a function which is implemented by one or more algorithms, which are selected depending on internal heuristics you, as a programmer, are not supposed to know or need to know much about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR: In short** it does not matter whether you perform matrix-matrix multiplications using *row-major* or *column-major* ordering with MKL (and other BLAS implementations).

---

> I know that c is a row major language, whereas dgemm is a column major algorithm.

DGEMM is **not** a *column-major* algorithm, it is the BLAS interface for computing a matrix-matrix product with general matrices. The common reference implementation for DGEMM (and most of BLAS) is [Netlib's](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) which is written in Fortran. The only reason it assumes column-major ordering is because Fortran is a column-major order language. DGEMM (and the corresponding BLAS Level 3 functions) is **not** specifically for *column-major* data.

#### What Does DGEMM Compute?

DGEMM in basic maths performs a 2D [matrix-matrix multiplication](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html). The standard [image: Order N^3] algorithm for multiplying 2D matrices requires you to traverse one matrix along its rows and the other along its columns. To perform the matrix-matrix multiplication, **AB** = **C**, we would multiply the rows of **A** by the columns of **B** to produce **C**. Therefore, the ordering of the input matrices does not matter as one matrix must be traversed along its rows and the other along its columns.

#### Investigating Row-Major and Column-Major DGEMM Computation with MKL

Intel MKL is smart enough to utilise this under the hood and provides the exact same performance for *row-major* and *column-major* data.

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, ...);
```

and

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, ...);
```

will execute with similar performance. We can test this with a relatively simple program

```
#include <float.h>
#include <mkl.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void init_matrix(double *A, int n, int m, double d);
void test_dgemm(CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout, double *A, double *B, double *C, const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, int nSamples, double *timing);
void print_summary(const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, const int nSamples, const double *timing);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MKL_INT n, k, m;
    double *a, *b, *c;
    double *timing;
    int nSamples = 1;

    if (argc != 5){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Wrong number of arguments!\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s mMatrix nMatrix kMatrix NSamples\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    m = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    k = atoi(argv[3]);

    nSamples = atoi(argv[4]);

    timing = malloc(nSamples * sizeof *timing);

    a = mkl_malloc(m*k * sizeof *a, 64);
    b = mkl_malloc(k*n * sizeof *a, 64);
    c = mkl_calloc(m*n, sizeof *a, 64);

    /** ROW-MAJOR ORDERING **/
    test_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, a, b, c, m, n, k, nSamples, timing);

    /** COLUMN-MAJOR ORDERING **/
    test_dgemm(CblasColMajor, a, b, c, m, n, k, nSamples, timing);

    mkl_free(a);
    mkl_free(b);
    mkl_free(c);
    free(timing);
}

void init_matrix(double *A, int n, int m, double d) {
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp for schedule (static) private(i,j)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            A[j + i*n] = d * (double) ((i - j) / n);
        }
    }
}

void test_dgemm(CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout, double *A, double *B, double *C, const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, int nSamples, double *timing) {
    int i;
    MKL_INT lda = m, ldb = k, ldc = m;
    double alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.0;

    if (CblasRowMajor == Layout) {
        printf("\n*****ROW-MAJOR ORDERING*****\n\n");
    } else if (CblasColMajor == Layout) {
        printf("\n*****COLUMN-MAJOR ORDERING*****\n\n");
    }

    init_matrix(A, m, k, 0.5);
    init_matrix(B, k, n, 0.75);
    init_matrix(C, m, n, 0);

    // First call performs any buffer/thread initialisation
    cblas_dgemm(Layout, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m, n, k, alpha, A, lda, B, ldb, beta, C, ldc);

    double tmin = DBL_MAX, tmax = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i) {
        init_matrix(A, m, k, 0.5);
        init_matrix(B, k, n, 0.75);
        init_matrix(C, m, n, 0);

        timing[i] = dsecnd();
        cblas_dgemm(Layout, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m, n, k, alpha, A, lda, B, ldb, beta, C, ldc);
        timing[i] = dsecnd() - timing[i];

        if (tmin > timing[i]) tmin = timing[i];
        else if (tmax < timing[i]) tmax = timing[i];
    }

    print_summary(m, n, k, nSamples, timing);
}

void print_summary(const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, const int nSamples, const double *timing) {
    int i;

    double tavg = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < nSamples; i++) {
        tavg += timing[i];
    }
    tavg /= nSamples;

    printf("#Loop | Sizes  m   n   k  | Time (s)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < nSamples; i++) {
        printf("%4d %12d %3d %3d  %6.4f\n", i + 1 , m, n, k, timing[i]);
    }

    printf("Summary:\n");
    printf("Sizes  m   n   k  | Avg. Time (s)\n");
    printf(" %8d %3d %3d %12.8f\n", m, n, k, tavg);
}
```

on my system this produces

```
$ ./benchmark_dgemm 1000 1000 1000 5
*****ROW-MAJOR ORDERING*****

#Loop | Sizes  m   n   k  | Time (s)
   1         1000 1000 1000  0.0589
   2         1000 1000 1000  0.0596
   3         1000 1000 1000  0.0603
   4         1000 1000 1000  0.0626
   5         1000 1000 1000  0.0584
Summary:
Sizes  m   n   k  | Avg. Time (s)
     1000 1000 1000   0.05995692

*****COLUMN-MAJOR ORDERING*****

#Loop | Sizes  m   n   k  | Time (s)
   1         1000 1000 1000  0.0597
   2         1000 1000 1000  0.0610
   3         1000 1000 1000  0.0581
   4         1000 1000 1000  0.0594
   5         1000 1000 1000  0.0596
Summary:
Sizes  m   n   k  | Avg. Time (s)
     1000 1000 1000   0.05955171
```

where we can see that there is very little difference between the *column-major* ordering time and the *row-major* ordering time. **0.0595 seconds** for *column-major* versus **0.0599** seconds for *row-major*. Executing this again might produce the following, where the row-major calculation is faster by **0.00003** seconds.

```
$ ./benchmark_dgemm 1000 1000 1000 5
*****ROW-MAJOR ORDERING*****

#Loop | Sizes  m   n   k  | Time (s)
   1         1000 1000 1000  0.0674
   2         1000 1000 1000  0.0598
   3         1000 1000 1000  0.0595
   4         1000 1000 1000  0.0587
   5         1000 1000 1000  0.0584
Summary:
Sizes  m   n   k  | Avg. Time (s)
     1000 1000 1000   0.06075310

*****COLUMN-MAJOR ORDERING*****

#Loop | Sizes  m   n   k  | Time (s)
   1         1000 1000 1000  0.0634
   2         1000 1000 1000  0.0596
   3         1000 1000 1000  0.0582
   4         1000 1000 1000  0.0582
   5         1000 1000 1000  0.0645
Summary:
Sizes  m   n   k  | Avg. Time (s)
     1000 1000 1000   0.06078266
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been meaning to do an analysis like this but been held up by other projects. Have you investigated the effect of row vs column on non square matrices? I have non square matrices (800x10) which I am multiplying by the transpose to get a conditioned matrix of (10x10) and I wonder if this same analysis holds when row and column dimensions are not the same.

Comment: @Laurbert515 I just benchmarked those matrix sizes and the difference between *row-major* and *column-major* is of the order of 1 microsecond, with the computation taking around 5 microseconds on my laptop. As in my answer sometimes *row-major* is quicker and sometimes *column-major*. Intel MKL will most times choose the optimal method to compute the result based on the input matrix sizes. However, *there **may** be times where you do actually need to perform the benchmarks yourself to determine the most optimal method*. For most people (and cases) it won't matter.

Comment: I executed several tests (via our C# MKL wrapper) and found a real difference (factor x2) between "col" and "row" matrices. Next code (vector as matrix X matrix) MKLAccess.AlignedMath.cblas_dgemm(NoTranspose, NoTranspose, 1.0, vectorMatrDouble, matrixMatrDouble, 0.0, resultMatrDouble); Also I tested cblas_dgemm vs. cblas_sgemm and in cause of "column" the tests show same time, but in case of "rows" show "x2" factor. Tested data: cblas_dgemm (A[1, 35] x B[35, 125324] =>R[1, 125324]